# Compiz/Unity - Focus window on specific monitor?

Tags: ubuntu, multiple-monitors, keyboard-shortcuts, ubuntu-unity, compiz

I'm on Ubuntu 15.10 using 4 monitors via an nvidia graphics card (dell XPS 8900). I almost always keep 4 full-screen applications (usually one of terminal, chrome or skype). Often I'll have multiples of the same app running, e.g. 3x terminator + 1x chrome.

Is there a way I can bind a key combination (Super-Ctrl-[1-4]) to select an app on a specific monitor? Something like alt-tab for changing focus, but scoped to apps only on one display.

I'm used to this functionality from when I leveraged tiling WMs like Awesome, but in general I find Unity to be a lot more usable for my work; how can I get this feature back?